# CoreLocation , MapKit Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, core-location

I Tried To Show My Current Location In Mapkit  and this is code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //Make this controller the delegate for the map view.
    self.MapView.delegate = self;     

    // Ensure that you can view your own location in the map view.
    [self.MapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
}
```

and I wrote This Delegate Of Mapkit

```
#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate methods. 
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {    
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locationManager.location.coordinate,2000,2000);


    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

But I Get Wrong Location Iam In Egypt And This Give ME iam in UnitedStates 
Any One Can Hep ME ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case: if you are using the simulator, the position will not be your real position. You have to set your location in the simulator:
Debug -> Location -> Custom Location (or anything else)

Comment: You have to enter the latitude and longitude of your position. So, start the simulator, go to debug -> location -> custom location and set it to 30.2, 31.5

Comment: BIG Thanks Nicholas :) 
i make this and it show me egypt in map but not the current location

Comment: Yes, I did. But since you just want the information once, it's easier to look it up on google maps by turning on LatLng-Shortinfo in the maps labs. Otherwise run your app on an iPhone and get the correct location from it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all.

You didnt used

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Please add this line after you initiate the location manager variable. Also please let me know if you are seeing this location USA in Simulator.

If it is: Your simulator simulates the location given by user preferences. Get to the simulator window, there you'll get the option to show custom location as per your selection. By default it is selected as USA.

Hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: i can't find user preferences ?
where can i fine it ?

Comment: When you run the Project, on the top of debug window there is a arrow key type button, You can use that too for custom location. Also there is option in iPhone Simulator, Debug>Location option.